# debug web service proxy class in C#

Tags: c#, web-services

In my project I have created a web application which has a web service. In the same solution I have added another web application. I am consuming the web service from this application. I have added a web reference using add web reference using web reference option. I want to debug the proxy class generated(when i add a web reference). I put a debugger in the proxy class but it did not work.Then I copied the proxy class and created the a new class in client web app with same same and same content and deleted the web reference. But still I am not able to debug the proxy class. How can i debug the proxy class? 
Please help.

Comment: How is the web service being hosted?

Comment: As per my limited knowledge, webservice and classes that make use of its operations do so by implementing an interface. Did you try implementing an interface for this purpose.

Comment: Do you want to debug the proxy itself or do you want to be able to debug the code on the service (step into it)?

Comment: What _"did not work"_ about it? Errors? Skipped breakpoints? You should be able to debug a service no matter what, so please describe what you have tried. Can you also post a small code sample that reproduces the problem, so other people can look into it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try removing `[DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]` from the generated code

Answer (score 7):

In Visual Studio 2010 you can set a break point (what you obviously have tried). But try running the web service solution by right clicking on your application selecting debug and click new start new instance.

The debug is just below the set as start up project option

Comment: But also note there is a difference between the normal run and the start new instance. I had this problem a lot of times (both running but the service not debugging), this being the solution.

Comment: Also, maybe one could mention that the defaults are producing an end to end communication protocol on the fly that is also found under the debug folder for the executables. Sometimes really helpful... and as another addition, if you have both projects in the same solution and vs studio, to import the service, you should really start the binary from the bin folder too, this way you can right click on the Project->Add Service Reference and use the wizzard.

Answer (score 6):

The way I normally do this is to host the client app and webservice hosting app in IIS locally. You should have two application virtual directories. Use a separate application pool for each application. When a successful request is made from the client app to the web service app there should be two worker processes (w3wp.exe processes). You should be able to attach your debugger to the correct w3wp process to debug it.

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio 2008\2010:

1. Set `<compilation debug="true">` in your web service application
2. Go to Tools\Options, then Debugging\General and uncheck **Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)**
3. Set the breakpoints in the proxy class (for the web service set one breakpoint on the Invoke and another on the return line)


   Debug as usual.


   If you see something like *step-into request resulted in automatic step-over of a property or operator*, just follow the instructions (right click on the line, uncheck "Step over properties and operators" or "Step into specific...").


   [image]

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this function ? 
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

Instead of putting a debugger, use above function, this might solve your problem.

Such as you want to debug a function test()

```
public bool test()
{
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
//..put it on top of the function
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a breakpoint just before you make a webservice call, and then `Step Into` (F11) the webservice call itself. Once inside the webservice, you can set more breakpoints wherever you want.

Answer (score 2):

As a supplement to other answers, you can also right-click the solution and select "Set StartUp Projects..."

Under Common Properties/Startup Project, select the radio option for "Multiple startup projects:" and then for your web service and proxy projects select Action "Start".

Debugging should now launch the debugger in both projects every time you hit run.

Answer (score 1):

Add in your code (in c#):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

Check if you build your project as "Solution Configurations: Debug".